# Linear combination of a set of vectors and a function of vectors in R

Tags: r, loops

Suppose we have three vectors x1, x2, x3 and also we have four vectors a0, a1, a2, a3 which we call coefficients.

```
x1 <- rnorm(10); x2 <- rnorm(10); x3 <- rnorm(10);
a0 <- runif(25); a1 <- runif(25); a2 <- runif(25); a3 <- runif(25);
```

I want to compute the following data frames L0, L1, L2, L3 (all of them will have 10 rows and 25 columns)

```
L0<-data.frame(matrix(0,nrow=10,ncol=25))
L1<-data.frame(matrix(0,nrow=10,ncol=25))
L2<-data.frame(matrix(0,nrow=10,ncol=25))
L3<-data.frame(matrix(0,nrow=10,ncol=25))

for (i in 1:10){
   L0[i,] <- a0 + mean(a1)*x1[i] + mean(a2)*x2[i] + mean(a3)*x3[i]
   L1[i,] <- mean(a0) + a1*x1[i] + mean(a2)*x2[i] + mean(a3)*x3[i]
   L2[i,] <- mean(a0) + mean(a1)*x1[i] + a2*x2[i] + mean(a3)*x3[i]
   L3[i,] <- mean(a0) + mean(a1)*x1[i] + mean(a2)*x2[i] + a3*x3[i] 
 }
```

I'm wondering how to make the coefficients `a` were used as vectors when I compute the corresponding L, but remain the rest of coefficients in that computation as a function of those coefficients (the `mean` in this example). Is there in **R** a better way to do what the last code does? Namely, compute each `L` through the set of vectors `a` so that in the computation of `L0`, the coefficient `a0` is used with all its elements, but the others `a1`, `a2`, `a3` are their correspondent mean; in the computation of `L1` the coefficient `a1` is used with all its elements, but the others `a0`, `a2`, `a3` are their correspondent mean, and so on.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid the `for` statement?

Comment: @ChiPak exactly. That is what I meant as the better way to do this. Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a nested `lapply` and `mapply` approach that ultimately creates a list of dataframes and as shown each element is equivalent to original L's. Two versions are demonstrated below.

**Longer version** *(using if logic)*

```
alternative_means_sums <- function(a,b,c,d) {  
  if (d == 1) {
    vec <- a0 + mean(a1)*a + mean(a2)*b + mean(a3)*c
  }
  if (d == 2) {
    vec <- mean(a0) + a1*a + mean(a2)*b + mean(a3)*c
  }
  if (d == 3) {
    vec <- mean(a0) + mean(a1)*a + a2*b + mean(a3)*c
  }
  if (d == 4) {
    vec <-mean(a0) + mean(a1)*a + mean(a2)*b + a3*c
  }
  return(vec)
}

dfList <- lapply(seq(4), function(i)
  data.frame(t(mapply(alternative_means_sums, x1, x2, x3, i))))

all.equal(dfList[[1]], L0)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(dfList[[2]], L1)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(dfList[[3]], L2)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(dfList[[4]], L3)
# [1] TRUE
```

**Shorter version**  *(collect all means in list, then by position remove unneeded mean and add the non-mean factor)*

```
a_list <- list(a0, a1, a2, a3)      # OR:   mget(ls(pattern="^a[0-9]$"))

alternative_means_sums <- function(a,b,c,d) { 
  args <- list(1,a,b,c)
  tmp <- c(mean(a0), mean(a1)*a, mean(a2)*b, mean(a3)*c)[-d]      
  vec <- sum(tmp) + a_list[[d]]*args[[d]]

  return(vec)
}

dfList2 <- lapply(seq(4), function(i)
  data.frame(t(mapply(alternative_means_sums, x1, x2, x3, i))))

all.equal(dfList2[[1]], L0)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(dfList2[[2]], L1)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(dfList2[[3]], L2)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(dfList2[[4]], L3)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: actually, I also tried something close to your longer version solution but using the `case` instruction. The shorter version is more in the direction of what I was trying to figure out. Thank you so much.

Comment: Great to hear! Glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using the `dplyr` package.  First, some set up:

```
library(dplyr)
A <- data.frame(a0, a1, a2, a3)
X <- cbind(1, x1, x2, x3)
```

Now we create a function to create the `L` dataframes.

```
L <- function(i, mat = A, fun = mean) {
  if (i + 1 > ncol(mat)) 
    stop("i must be less than or equal to number of 'a' vectors")
  out <- mutate_at(mat, seq(ncol(mat))[-(i + 1)], fun)
  out <- as.data.frame(X %*% t(as.matrix(out)))
  colnames(out) <- paste0("X", seq(nrow(mat)))
  out
}
```

The `mutate_at` function transforms the values in each column in the `A` dataframe to the column mean, except for the column indicated in `i`.  We then use matrix multiplication to get the desired output.  The last step renames the columns in the output in the format `X1, X2, ..., X25` to match the original `L0, L1` etc dataframes.

So we have

```
all.equal(L(0), L0)
[1] TRUE
```

We can also do

```
out <- lapply(0:3, L)
all.equal(out[[1]], L0)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(out[[2]], L1)
# [1] TRUE
```

and so on.